# Out of Memory Listing Custom Post type in Admin?

Tags: wordpress, memory, crash, custom-post-type

This is a very strange and serious problem. Going to "**All Images**" in my **admin** area (equivalent of all posts) shows a **memory exhausted** error, and white screen. And this is after upping memory to a very high amount.

I guess I am wondering why SO much memory is needed to build what is simply a list?

I assume it must be an error on my part, coding. Perhaps I've done something wrong in declaring the post type? What are some common "gotchas" in this area? I'd hate to just say "increase memory" because that seems like a weak work around for a serious problem.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-image_columns', 'symbiostock_image_manager_edit_columns' );
function symbiostock_image_manager_edit_columns( $columns )
{
    $columns = array(
         'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'image_preview' => 'Preview',
        'date' => 'Uploaded',
        'title' => 'Image Name',
        'description' => 'Description',
        'exclusive' => 'Exclusive',
        'price_bloggee' => 'Bloggee',
        'price_small' => 'Small',
        'price_medium' => 'Medium',
        'price_large' => 'Large',
        'price_vector' => 'Vector',
        'cat' => 'Category',
        'tag' => 'Keywords' 
    );

    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_image_posts_custom_column', 'symbiostock_image_manager_custom_columns' );
function symbiostock_image_manager_custom_columns( $column )
{
    global $post;

    $custom = get_post_custom();

    switch ( $column ) {

         case 'date':            

            break;      

        case 'image_preview':

            echo '<img class="admin_preview_pic" alt="Image Preview" src="' . $custom['symbiostock_minipic'][0] . '" />';

            break;

        case 'description':

            the_excerpt();

            break;

        case 'exclusive':

            echo $exclusive = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $custom[ "exclusive" ][ 0 ]));

            break;

        case 'discount_percent':

            echo $discount_percent = $custom[ "discount_percent" ][ 0 ];

            break;

        case 'price_bloggee':

            echo $price_bloggee = $custom[ "price_bloggee" ][ 0 ];


            break;

        case 'price_small':

            echo $custom[ "price_small" ][ 0 ];

            break;

        case 'price_medium':

            echo $custom[ "price_medium" ][ 0 ];

            break;

        case 'price_large':

            echo $custom[ "price_large" ][ 0 ];

            break;

        case 'price_vector':

            echo $custom[ "price_vector" ][ 0 ];

            break;

        case 'cat':

            echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'image-type', '', ', ', '' );

            break;

        case 'tag':

            echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'image-tags', '', ', ', '' );

            break;

    } //$column    
}
```

Maybe there is a problem on how I've declared the custom post type. Here's the code just in case:

```
register_taxonomy( 'image-tags', array(
     'image' 
), array(
     'hierarchical' => false,
     'rewrite' => true,
     'query_var' => true,
    'singular_label' => 'Image Keyword',
    'exclude_from_search' =>false,
    'hierarchical'            => false,
    'labels'                  => $labels,
    'show_ui'                 => true,
    'show_admin_column'       => true,

    'slug' => 'image-tag',               
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Image Keywords', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Keywords', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Images' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Image Keywords' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Image Keyword' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Image Keyword' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Image Keyword' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Keyword Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Image Keywords' ),
        ),
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'search-images', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
        'with_front' => false, 
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Check for (endless) recursive calls in your code. They could exhaust memory pretty fast. I also don't think the code shown is the problem. What's the exact error?

Comment: I've just posted some more code that might be responsible for problems. In the meantime, I'll track down that exact error.

Comment: Try to make the columns in `symbiostock_image_manager_custom_columns` work one by one.

Comment: Will do. And its a typical wordpress "memory exhausted" error, to answer Bart.

Comment: How much memory are you giving to PHP? What is error in the error log?

Comment: probably too many plugins are activated, some of which can also be preforming other operations on your code, or conflicting .